# org-complete-tags-always-offer-all-agenda-tags does not provide all tags

Tags: org-mode, org-tags

Running emacs 25.2.2.

In my `init.el`, I have:

```
(org-complete-tags-always-offer-all-agenda-tags t)
```

So, when I `C-c C-q` on a headline in any org file, I expect it to show me tags from **all** agenda files. However, it does not.

I have a lot of tags defined using `#+TAGS: some(s) thing(t)` method. They all are shown. I can hit `TAB` and it will offer to complete tags. **But** that is **only** from that file.

How do I get the expected behaviour --- tags from all Org files are offered?

Comment: Is that a customization? IOW, is the form inside a `(custom-set-variables ...)` form? FWIW, when I set it by hand locally in a buffer, I get tags from all agenda files (*NOT* all org files: the latter is clearly impossible).

Comment: @Nick Yes. It is a customization. I did `M-x customize-variable RET org-complete-tags-always-offer-all-agenda-tags RET` to change the default and set the value. How did you set it by hand locally in a buffer?

Comment: I just did `M-: (setq-local org-complete-tags-always-offer-all-agenda-tags t) RET` but I suspect that it's version related: what version of org mode are you running?

Comment: @Nick I have not installed org mode explicitly. But the documentation is for 8.2.9. So, I assume I am running the same version :)

Comment: Do `M-x org-version` to make sure. I believe 8.2.9 is the version that was bundled with Emacs 24, but it is getting long in the tooth: it was released in 2014.

Comment: @Nick Org version is 8.2.10.

Comment: @Nick I did try `M-: (setq-local org-complete-tags-always-offer-all-agenda-tags t) RET` but it produced no effect